# Filteration in where clause: syntax error?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Please help me to sort this query:

```
WHERE
RECEIPT_DATE BETWEEN( Coalesce(@FROM_DATE,RECEIPT_DATE) AND Coalesce(@TO_DATE,RECEIPT_DATE) )
AND 
OFFICE_ID=Coalesce(@OFFICE_ID,OFFICE_ID)
```

Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WHERE
   RECEIPT_DATE BETWEEN 
      Coalesce(@FROM_DATE, RECEIPT_DATE) AND Coalesce(@TO_DATE, RECEIPT_DATE) 
   AND 
   OFFICE_ID = Coalesce(@OFFICE_ID, OFFICE_ID)
```

You need to have two dates following the `BETWEEN` (`BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2`) and no brackets around that.

Answer (score 1):

Check this query its working fine with no errors

```
declare @FROM_DATE datetime
declare @TO_DATE datetime
declare @OFFICE_ID int
select * from table1 WHERE
(RECEIPT_DATE BETWEEN  Coalesce(@FROM_DATE,RECEIPT_DATE) AND Coalesce(@TO_DATE,RECEIPT_DATE) )
AND 
OFFICE_ID=Coalesce(@OFFICE_ID,OFFICE_ID)
```

Mistake in your where clause is

```
BETWEEN (
```

because you cannot put ( after BETWEEN.

Answer (score 1):

`BETWEEN` is a keyword, not a function, so doesn't take parenthesis. Try wrapping the entire logical construct if you are finding the placement of the `AND` confusing.

```
WHERE (X BETWEEN A AND B) AND (Y = C)
```